# how to get bootstrap-slider min and max value input

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I want to use bootstrap-slider js and get 2 min and max value after clicking on submit button. 
this is what i want to achieve after clicking on submit button:
domain.com?min_id=10&max_id=100

```
<form>
 <input name="min_id">
 <input name="max_id">
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(form).submit(function(e) {
    $get("domain.com?min_id="+input.attr("min_id")+"&max_id="+input.attr("max_id"))
}
```